# Yii2 Two different way for breadcrumbs

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app, gii

I have a gii generated view.php page, which can be reached from two different paths, but the breadcrumbs is the same. Anyone know how to fix?

Let me explain: I have the view.php view which shows the summary of the report made and can be reached from two paths:

- when I create a new report and therefore the path should be HOME / CREATION / VIEW;
- and also from a section that shows the user the summary of the reports she sent and therefore the breadcrumbs should be HOME / SUMMARY / VIEW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have 2 options to know where it came from:

- Send a query variable on each link or in the redirection to manually build the breadcumb. Like: `$value = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('breadcumb')`
- Other option is to get the referrer url. And base on the value you can pass it to the switch. You can get referrer's url using: `$value = Yii::$app->request->getReferrer()`.

2. Then do a switch to build the link:

   ```
   switch(value) {
     case 'creation':
      $label = 'CREATION';
      $url = 'url_of_creation';
      break;
     case 'summary':
      $label = 'SUMMARY';
      $url = 'url_of_summary'; 
      break;
   }
   ```
3. Then just do something like this:

`$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $label, 'url' => $url];`

Comment: I LOVE YOU!!<3<3<3 I used the switch and it works great

Comment: One question, I have a link which at the end has the alert id, how do I indicate the number on the switch case?
http: // localhost / web / reporting / update / %% where the id of the report goes in place of the percentage.

Comment: Dependends on your URLManager configuration, you need to see how you can get the variable from the url, or I guess it's just $_GET['id'], but this is a new question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a short breadcrum solution using `match()`:

```
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = match($path) {
    'creation' => ['label' => 'Creation', 'url' => Url::to['creation'],
    'summary' => ['label' => 'Summary', 'url' => Url::to['summary'],
};
```

`$path` should either be set in the controller or determined by [`Yii::$app->request->getReferrer()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request#getReferrer()-detail).

Please note, that this requires PHP8.